# Compress audio (mp3,3gpp) file in android before uploading it to server?

Tags: android, audio, compression, lossless-compression

Is their any library or any other method in android that could (lossless compression) compress audio files in android.
P.s. Please refer to a library that has good documentation bcoz I found ffmpeg but was not able to use it .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library, which uses ffmpeg but with a nice java interface:
https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/blob/master/README.md